# Manage popview and pushview flip landscape animation

Tags: navigation, xib, pushviewcontroller, flip, popviewcontroller

I have some nibs with the same background image.

- welcome screen (full screen)
- companies list screen (navigation bar and tool bar)
- and other ones not important in this case.

On my welcome screen i have a button in the middle of the screen for pushing next view to companies screen.
My problem is, when I flip, the animation runs but because of navigation bar and tool bar, background size is modified and animation is jumpy because it loads the view before showing it. Same problem in other way, when i press back button on navigation bar, jumpy animation ...

is anyone already had this kind of problem ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I find my solution,
 in the fonction :

```
[UIView transitionFromView:currentController.view toView:self.companyViewController.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
```

i set the last argument (completion) to nil.
and i make my own animation just after.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.companyViewController animated:YES];
```